# How do I address people who give feedback?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, salutations

Do I call them 'Respondent' or are there better words to use?

Example of the feedback as follows:

```
====================================================================
| Question                                  | Rate (1 to 10: Best) |
====================================================================
| Technical Knowledge                       |                      |
====================================================================
| Communication Skills                      |                      |
====================================================================
```

When the feedback is completed, there will be an email sent to the owner.

```
Dear Mr. Jack,

There is a feedback from a _______ as follows:

====================================================================
| Question                                  | Rate (1 to 10: Best) |
====================================================================
| Technical Knowledge                       | 8                    |
====================================================================
| Communication Skills                      | 9                    |
====================================================================
```

Also, there will be a report sent to the owner to sum up each week feedback as follows:

```
Dear Mr. Jack,

The following is the feedback for week (1/Jan/2012 to 7/Jan/2012):

====================================================================
| Total ____________                        | 150                  |
====================================================================
| Technical Knowledge (Mean Score)          | 8.97                 |
====================================================================
| Communication Skills (Mean Score)         | 9.21                 |
====================================================================
```

The question would be what should I fill in the blank (***_*____**) as shown in the above?

Should it be 'Respondent' or 'Correspondent' or 'Responder' or 'Commenter' or are there better words for it?

Comment: I never see "respondent" here on ELU. *Poster* sometimes, but actually I think we don't really have suitable words. Pretend it's like someone you were just introduced to at a party, but you forgot their name. It turns out to be really easy to avoid using any form of address at all if you've got a good reason not to (such as not knowing what word/title/name to use! :)

Comment: Include some context please.

Comment: Try calling them **feeders-back** and see what they say...

Comment: @Eduardo Added more information, please provide your suggestions and comments.

Comment: What are they before they are a respondant? You are already saying that they have provided feedback, so can you not just call them "student" or suchlike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, *you* are the "respondent". You are responding to the person's feedback. "Respondent" is the term for a person who must, or is supposed to, respond to something. For example, if you file a lawsuit, then the respondent is the person you are suing, because they are expected to respond to the lawsuit.

If by "how do I address" you mean you want to know the *form of address*, that is, an appropriate salutation when writing back to a person who gave feedback, here are several options to consider:

> Dear Reader,
>
> Dear Commenter,
>
> Dear Customer, (if appropriate in the situation)
>
> Dear Sir/Madam, (formal, inclusive language)

Answer (score 1):

Just imagine that there is an exact word for what you are looking for. Let's imagine that the word is *feedbacker*. Now imagine the following sentence, as you provided it:

> There is a feedback from a *feedbacker* as follows:

Don't you think it would be a little bit redundant? Maybe if you used the other function of the person, as Schroedingers Cat suggested, like *student* or suchlike, it would be much better.

It's like saying:

> I've bought an apple from a seller (from whom if not?)
>   I've sold the item to a buyer (to whom if not?)

IMO you should avoid that redundancy or at least make it more useful by adding some more specific term such as *student*.

In the case of the last example:

```
====================================================================
| Total ____________                        | 150                  |
====================================================================
| Technical Knowledge (Mean Score)          | 8.97                 |
====================================================================
| Communication Skills (Mean Score)         | 9.21                 |
====================================================================
```

I would simply use the term *feedbacks*. There is no need to reference the people that made the feedbacks. The important thing is the feedback itself, not the person that made it, even to the extent that feedbacks are usually anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

> Reviewer

I know that the accepted answer helped you restructure your address *in general*, but keep in mind that, in many cases, "reviewer" is the common name for such a person.  They were able to provide feedback because the *reviewed* the work.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. *Responder* as a generic term
2. Context specific term not a synonym of *responder*
3. Context specific synonym of *responder*

Feederbacker is not an option.

Comment: I would not favor *responder* because it carries other connotations, in my mind, at least: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_first_responder

Answer (score 0):

How about "[correspondent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/correspondent)"?