# What to call a person who replies to your comment

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you call somebody who asks a question and somebody who answers a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/what-do-you-call-somebody-who-asks-a-question-and-somebody-who-answers-a-questio)

In a conversation, if person A replies to person B, what do we call A and B?

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't clear.
I need to know what to call "A" and "B". I'm involved in a project to create a comment system. So, B makes a comment... A replies to B's comment.

Comment: More information would be helpful.  Did B ask A a question? Or is A giving an unsolicited response?

Comment: Related to various degrees, and possible duplicates: [What do you call somebody who asks a question and somebody who answers a question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/) [How do I address people who give feedback?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55366/), [What do I call a person who is participating in a survey?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18022/) [Should I prefer “asker” or “questioner” for a person who asked a question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60179/)

Answer (score 4):

For the person who answers, *[respondent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/respondent#Noun)* or *[correspondent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/correspondent#Noun)* are reasonable.  (Some of the previous questions mentioned in comments also suggest *answerer* and *interviewee*.)

For the enquirer/asker/questioner/interrogator/interviewer, my preference is  *[interlocutor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interlocutor#Noun)* (“A person who takes part in dialogue or conversation” or “man in the middle of the line in a minstrel show who questions the end men and acts as leader”).

*Edit:* As noted in a comment, and as is quite obvious from first sense in the definition quoted above, *interlocutor* applies to all persons engaged in a conversation.  In following, let *first sense* denote the first sense mentioned above, ie conversation participant; let *second sense* denote the second sense mentioned above, ie, minstrel leader; and let *other senses* refer to less-relevant third or fourth senses like “An interlocutory judgement or sentence” or “Someone who takes part in talks as a representative of another person or organization”.

Regarding the second sense: [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interlocutor) includes first and second senses in much the same words as Wiktionary.  [Wordnik.com](http://www.wordnik.com/words/interlocutor) has both senses, in slightly different words.  [Memidex.com](http://www.memidex.com/interlocutor) shows the following dictionaries (or things resembling dictionaries) as having at least senses one and two:  Collins Dictionary, Wiktionary, Merriam-Webster, New World Dictionary, American Heritage Dictionary, Encarta Dictionary.  In its quotes of the following dictionaries, Memidex shows at least sense one, with sense two not shown: Oxford Dictionary, Macmillan British Dictionary, Cambridge Dictionary.

These lineups suggest that sense two (minstrel leader) of *interlocutor* is not found in British dictionaries and is commonly found in American dictionaries.

Comment: Interlocutor is rather general and applies to any person exchanging /having a conversation with another person. They are both interlocutors. :)

Comment: @Alenanno, of course the first sense of *interlocutor* applies as you say.  The second doesn't; hence your comment might not apply if the question's conversation is among men in a line in a minstrel show.

Comment: There are no secondary meanings, as far as I know, and the NOAD/OED both confirm this. That additional meaning you provide doesn't really apply to the question (or at least it's what it seems to me). On the OALD it gives another meaning (the only dictionary I've seen that does so far), but it still doesn't apply here (synonym of spokesman), not interviewer.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Is there a better word or noun for person "A" other than respondent or (replier?). The scenario is this:  person B makes a comment, A then replies to B's comment

Comment: @Alenanno, see edit re secondary meanings.   Nikorasu, perhaps call them all commentators, conversationalists, correspondents.  I hesitate to mention it, but if the milieu is entirely informal consider *spuds* [1](http://www.ahajokes.com/pun07.html),[2](http://www.cafemom.com/journals/read/26154/Tater_Joke).